# AutoHotKey to recognise python Spyder IDE window

Tags: python, autohotkey, spyder

I want to use AHK exclusively in python Spyder IDE, so commands like

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Spyder
^u::Send print 3{Enter}
```

But seems AHK doesn't recognise Spyder window so it's not activated. What shall I put in place of **Spyder** for AHK to recognise it?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, don't forget to "close" your #IfWinActive at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, found the answer...

Just need to delete **ahk_class**

Details are in the help pages of function [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm)